# How do I view the logs of a run?

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli

According to the [GitHub CLI docs for `gh run view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_run_view), I should be able to query the logs of a run with this command:

```bash
gh run view --log <run-id>
```

For instance, to get the full log for [run `2796702959`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/actions/runs/2796702959) in the `vitejs/vite` repo:

```bash
gh run view -R vitejs/vite --log 2796702959
```

But that command returns nothing. Enabling debug reveals no errors:

```bash
GH_DEBUG=true gh run view -R vitejs/vite --log 2796702959
⣾* Request at 2022-08-04 19:55:51.795659 -0500 CDT m=+0.012528935
* Request to https://api.github.com/repos/vitejs/vite/actions/runs/2796702959
⣻* Request took 283.249521ms
* Request at 2022-08-04 19:55:52.08233 -0500 CDT m=+0.299195200
* Request to https://api.github.com/repos/vitejs/vite/actions/runs/2796702959/jobs
⣾%
```

*<sup>**Env**: macOS Big Sur, `gh` v2.11.3, GNU `bash` v3.2.57</sup>*

How do I actually query the run's logs with `gh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `gh` v2.11.3, that particular command is buggy ([`cli/cli#5011`](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5011)).

A workaround is to use a Bash script to call the API directly via `gh api`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e

REPO_NAME=${1?Missing repo name argument} # example: vitejs/vite
RUN_ID=${2?Missing run ID argument}

ZIPFILE=$(mktemp)
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)

Color_Off='\033[0m'
BBlack='\033[1;30m'
On_Cyan='\033[46m'

function downloadLogs() {
  echo "downloading logs for run $RUN_ID ..."
  gh api /repos/$REPO_NAME/actions/runs/$RUN_ID/logs > $ZIPFILE
  unzip -d $TMPDIR $ZIPFILE
  rm -f $ZIPFILE
}

function dumpLogs() {
  find $TMPDIR -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
      echo
      basefile=$(basename "$file")
      echo -e "${BBlack}${On_Cyan} $basefile ${Color_Off}"
      echo

      cat "$file"
    done
}

downloadLogs
dumpLogs
```

*Usage:*

```bash
./gh-logs.sh <repo-name> <run-id>
```

*Example:*

```bash
./gh-logs.sh vitejs/vite 2796702959 | less -R
```